# How to seek to a specific time in Subtitle Workshop

Tags: video, avi, subtitles, playback, video-conversion

I'm trying to add subtitles to an AVI file. I need to seek to a specific time. Using the slider isn't accurate enough. How can this be done in Subtitle Workshop? Is there some other video player that would be helpful for this?

Comment: You can give [Subtitle Horse](http://subtitle-horse.com/) a shot. It's an online tool which seems to have what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Subtitle Edit - it can seek to a specific time down to milliseconds and can also show waveform (or even spectrogram) for easier manual sync: http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/Help#video_modes